# In what order are the hats displayed on a user's profile?

Tags: discussion, sorting, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

In what order are the hats displayed on a user's profile (not to confuse with a similar question regarding the order of the hats on the leader board)?

For example, here is the order on my profile:

[image]

On past winter bashes, I recall the regular hats appeared before the secret hats.

Now they seem to be mixed together.

It's not the order in which I earned the hats.

What's more interesting - the order for different users seems to be similar, but not identical.

For example, here's another user's hats (Panda):

[image]

You can see that both of us have "Flashlight" and "Cruse of Oil" at the first two spots, and "Take This!" at the last spot. However, my "Wa-boushi" hat appears before my "Matryoshka" hat, where it's the opposite for the other user.

Comment: @Panda well you're featured anyway, #1 on MSE and #2 on the whole network. :-)